# How do you increase a Blade's strength?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

There are a lot of merc missions that require a certain strength to proceed with them. Since this seems to be the only thing in the game using strength, is it right to assume that just sending them on merc missions will increase their strength? Or do they have to be the leader, or is it entirely random?

Comment: Done a lot of missions with some persistent teams, and I don't really think strength is supposed to be increased at all.

Comment: Also, some people say that strength actually increases damage of physical arts.

Comment: @lentinant strength definitely goes up. Kora for me started at 20 something str, and is now up to 37. Wulfric is up to 57. I just need to know how it goes up. It looks like merc missions but it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand the correlation, but for the lot of blades I checked, it seems to be +/-2 from the number of orbs they've unlocked in the affinity tree. So, the safest bet is to just unlock more orbs and strength will go up as a result.